# Как вывести максимальное значение, если нет отрицательных элементов в строке

Tags: java

Задание:

> Создать программу, которая вводит c клавиатуры квадратный двумерный массив целых чисел и заменяет все элементы, лежащие на главной диагонали, числом положительных элементов соответствующей строки, если они есть или максимальным элементом, если их нет. Вывести результирующий массив на экран

Реализация:

```
package com.example.mas;

public class arr6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{4, 3, -1, -1},
                     {5, -2, 3, 1},
                     {0, 8, -9, 0},
                     {9, 5, 2, 0}};
        int i, j, max, c;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            c = 0;
            max = a[i][0];
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] > 0) {
                    c++;
                }
                if (a[i][j] > max) {
                    max = a[i][j];
                }
                if (a[i][j] < 0) {
                    a[i][i] = c;
                }
                else {
                    a[i][i] = max;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Присвоение диагонального элемента должно быть вне внутреннего цикла, а в проверке что выводить (число положительных элементов или максимальный элемент) должно участвовать число положительных элементов:

```
int[][] array = {{ 4, 3, -1, -1 },
                 { 5, -2, 3, 1 },
                 { -2, -8, -9, -5 },
                 { 9, 5, 2, 0 }};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    int positiveNumbersCount = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int element : array[i])
    {
        if (element > 0)
        {
            positiveNumbersCount++;
        }
        else if (element > max)
        {
            max = element;
        }
    }
    if (positiveNumbersCount > 0)
    {
        array[i][i] = positiveNumbersCount;
    }
    else
    {
        array[i][i] = max;
    }
}

for (int[] subArray : array)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray));
```